# CGI script shows source code when run

Tags: python, mysql, xampp, cgi

I am trying to make a simple CGI script that presents someones name based on what they enter into a html form, but once I submit the form it shows the source code of the CGI file.

Here is the code to the html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="processname.cgi" method="post">
                Please enter your name:
                <input type="text" name="firstname" autofocus="autofocus" required="required">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submitname" value="Submit Name!">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code to the cgi script:

```
#!C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
import cgi 

def htmlTop():
    print("""Content-type:text/html\n\n
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>My server side template</title>
    </head>
    <body>""")

def htmlTail():
    print("""</body>
    </html>""")

def getData():
    formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
    firstname = formData.getvalue("firstname")
    return firstname

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        htmlTop()
        firstName = getData()
        print("Hello {0}".format(firstName))
        htmlTail()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: What's the motivation behind using CGI here? This is what we did in the days when we lived in caves and had to chisel our computers out of bits of stone. With frameworks like Django this is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that useful comment.

Comment: Sarcastic, yes, but I'm serious: Why CGI? This has enormous risks associated with it and makes your life far more difficult than it should be. Unless this is a purely academic experiment there's far better ways to achieve these goals.

Comment: You're right, I am using this purely for academic reasons.

Comment: If that's the case then you need to learn about how to configure your server in CGI mode. Getting XAMPP which, presumably, uses Apache `httpd` to do the serving part means mucking around with `httpd` configuration files, specifically the [`cgi-bin` support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html).

Comment: By the way, you mentioned risks, would you mind outlining some of the risks associated with it?

Comment: CGI launches a Python process *per request* and is extremely inefficient. Modern Python applications use [wSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) which involves a persistent Python process that can serve many requests. CGI was the first solution towards running scripting code on the web (circa 1994) and it was very quickly replaced with something better.

Comment: I searched up what to do and have been to the `httpd` file and I edited a few things but I think it is more to do with how I made this cgi file which personally I don't know how to do.

Comment: As for the other risks, you have zero protection here from common [common vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) which you *will* get with any decent framework if you use it correctly. From an academic perspective CGI *forces* you to absorb nearly twenty five years of security lessons in the most painful way possible. With a framework at least you can learn as you go, while still writing secure code.

Comment: Now I genuinely thank you.

Answer (score -1):

That's mean that your cgi file script is considerate as a simple text file, so I guess your web server does'nt redirect the file content to python module to be handled and converted to the appropriate html. It may be because the web server is bad configured to use cgi.

Comment: How do I make a cgi file?

Comment: which web server are you using?

Comment: XAMPP is the web server I am using.

Comment: No xamp is not web server, it's a platform, you are using xamp with nginx or with apache?

Comment: this is what you need https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Apache is what I am using, my bad.